# How can i parse the id into my variable in angular?

Tags: php, angularjs

How can i parse the id key into my angular js variable? I want to convert the following PHP code into angular js.

```
<?php foreach($workTypes as $id => $name) {  ?>
<td class='pushCentre'><?php echo $day['userData']['quantities'][$id]; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

My try in Angular JS v1

```
    <td ng-repeat='(id, name) in workTypes' class='pushCentre'>
{{ day.userData.quantities.{{id}} }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 <td ng-repeat='(id, name) in workTypes' class='pushCentre'>
    {{ day.userData.quantities[id] }}</td>
```